# ArcGIS 10.1 - Re-writing an add-in application from processing an SDE Geodatabase to processing a file Geodatabase

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, add-in

ArcGIS 10.1- I am planing to re-write an Add-in application targeting SDE Geodatabase(ArcObjects) to an add-in application targeting file Geodatabase.

The Add-in application is a Tool that allow the end user to select a set of features and return the list of attributes values related to the selected features into a combo box. I've also another button on the toolbar that perform upstream tracing following the user placed point on the feature.

I am looking at what are the changes that I have to make and best practices to use.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: That sounds very rudimentary and it should not matter what sort of database the feature class is stored in. Could you post your code, or at least clarify whether you are using ArcObjects or arcpy?

Comment: Yes I am using ArcObjects

Answer (score 3):

Using ArcObjects, this is more or less straight forward. You use mostly the same interfaces, like IFeatureWorkspace, IFeatureClass, IFeatureDataset etc.

The main difference is the IWorkSpaceFactory being used; replace SdeWorkspaceFactory with FileGDBWorkspaceFactory. I have created several tools that targets both types using the same code.

There are a few differences though, for example, max lengths of dataset/ feature class names etc.